# How to get Facebook vanity or custom URL for fan page, in lieu of ugly numbered id URL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

When creating a Facebook fan page, it is assigned a long URL containing a unique ID number.  What prerequisites and steps are required to get a Facebook fan page vanity / custom URL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a guide to doing that [here](http://www.nirmaltv.com/2009/08/18/how-to-get-a-vanity-url-for-facebook-pages-and-applications/).

Essentially just go to http://www.facebook.com/username/ and click "Set a username for your pages" where you will be prompted with options to set up a custom URL for any of your pages.